# Program during the claim function

Tags: pda, cpi, vesting

This is the error info:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4465:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4424:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:284:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:144:14)
      at Object.rpc [as claimVestment] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

Could there be a problem with this:

```
token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.vested_tokens.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.beneficiary_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.vested_tokens.to_account_info(),
                },
                &[&[
                    b"vested-tokens",
                    vestment.key().as_ref(), //probably the problem
                    &[*ctx.bumps.get("vested-tokens").unwrap()],
                ]],
            ),
            *amount_to_claim,
        )?;

        vestment.amount_claimed = vestment.amount_claimed.checked_add(*amount_to_claim).unwrap();

        if vestment.amount_vested-vestment.amount_claimed==0 {
            vestment.is_active=false;
        }
```

In tests, this is how I call this instruction:

```
const txClaim1 = await program.rpc.claimVestment({
            accounts: {
                ledger: ledger,
                vestment: newVestment,
                beneficiary: beneficiary.publicKey,
                beneficiaryTokenAccount: beneficiaryTokenAccount,
                vestedTokens: vestedTokens,
                vestedTokensMint: tokenMint,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            },
            signers: [beneficiary],
        });

        await connection.confirmTransaction(txClaim1);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

without knowing anything about this bumps feature, i assume the error is unwrapping `ctx.bumps.get("vested-tokens")` and that the string is supposed to be snake case

but more broadly to debug this sort of issue, "Program failed to complete" means a panic. i would:

- disable preflight checks on your connection object (i dont know offhand how this is done in anchor, `Provider` tries to hide a lot of details like this)
- run `solana-test-validator` yourself
- run `solana logs -u l` alongside it
- run `anchor test` with `--skip-local-validator`

and look at the logs produced to find the actual error. `msg!` can be used to print whatever you need inside the program

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful info, will update you once I check your tips out!

Comment: Unfortunately, none of that works for me :/ By debugging I've come to the conclusion that my program doesn't even run the const txClaim1 line, as it for some reason breaks before that.